# add image on top of div css + jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a div that is styled like a box. It is dragged using jQuery UI. When it is dragged I would like to add an image to the top of the box. The image should be overlapping the box, so background is out of the question.

1. How do I add such image? Do I use append?
2. The draggable box has a dynamic z-index set by jQuery UI. How do I make sure that appended image is at least +1 to be on top?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the image with `prepend`, and position it absolutely:

```
var $mainBox = $('#main-box')
                    .prepend('<img class="centered" src="..." />')
                    .css('position', 'relative'),

    $img = $mainBox.find('.centered');

$img.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '-20px', // change this to whatever you want
    left: ( $mainBox.width() - $img.width() ) / 2
});
```

---

A better approach would be to have the `img` there all along, and just show/hide it when dragging. That way, you can keep your CSS where it belongs, and you won't have to shuffle elements in and out of the DOM.

Comment: True, but before I have the boxes dragged they are positioned to the side, one above the other. Won't the image, even hidden mess that position? If not, how would that code look like?

Comment: @santa: As long as the image is inside of the div, it cannot mess up the positions.

Comment: You're right +1. I also think hiding it will be better because currently every time I move a div it appends another image... And I think in my case I need to have another div with the image set as a background, because when I drop the main-box I need to change the image to another one.

Comment: ...or image without a div would be fine too. It works as a handle.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have problems with losing focus the second you place another element over your draggable. You need to change your flow so the draggable element has the box inside it.

```
<div class="draggable-item">
 <div class="show-on-drag"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```